# Can I use DoxyGen to document ActionScript code?

Tags: configuration, actionscript, documentation, doxygen

How do I Configuring DoxyGen to document ActionScript files?

I've included the *.as and *.asi files in doxygen's search pattern, but the classes, functions and variables don't show there.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Instead of doxygen you should use a documentation generator that specifically supports the language. For ActionScript 2, you have a couple choices:

1. [NaturalDocs](http://www.naturaldocs.org/) ([example](http://www.naturaldocs.org/example/showstyle.html?Default)) (free)
2. [ZenDoc](http://www.zendoc.org) (free)
3. [AS2Doc Pro](http://www.as2doc.com/) ([example](http://www.as2doc.com/examples/xhtml/)) (commercial)

If you are using ActionScript 3, Adobe includes a free documentation generator along with their open source compiler (the [Flex SDK](http://www.adobe.com/products/flex/flexdownloads/index.html#sdk)), called "[ASDoc](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/201/html/wwhelp/wwhimpl/common/html/wwhelp.htm?context=LiveDocs_Book_Parts&file=asdoc_127_1.html)". If you are using [FlashDevelop](http://www.flashdevelop.org/wikidocs/index.php?title=Features), the [latest beta](http://www.flashdevelop.org/community/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=3589) has a built in GUI for running ASDoc, so you don't have to dirty your hands with the commandline.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to produce SOME documentation with DoxyGen (What can I say - I like its features and capabilities) By doing the following:

Add *.as and *.asi to the list of file types to input.

Select:

```
OPTIMIZE_OUTPUT_JAVA   = YES
EXTRACT_ALL            = YES
HIDE_UNDOC_MEMBERS     = NO
HIDE_UNDOC_CLASSES     = NO
```

Another issue in AS3 is the package statement.
You need to tell DoxyGen to ignore the package definition. This is easy to do using cond.
So you'll change the line:

```
package myPackage {
```

into

```
/// @cond
package myPackage {
/// @endcond
```

Which will cause Doxygen to ignore the line(s) between cond and endcond.
Note that there seems to be no need to do the same for the closing curly bracket at the bottom of your .as file.

Comment: It doesn't work for me. Doxygen doesn't recognize the grammar of AS3 at all. It incorrectly parses the function bodies as "Public Member Functions", etc.

Answer (score 2):

You can also use Ortelius. Its easier to use than ASDoc since it comes with a simple GUI, and its more forgiven to your code. Its free and opensource, but windows only.

[ortelius.marten.dk](http://ortelius.marten.dk)